# Autocomplete Codeigniter when using get_instance()

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm, codeigniter-3

Within PHPStorm, I have been able to get autocomplete working with Codeigniter by adding a file to config/autocomplete.php which contains properties.  PhpStorm is able to read this file, and allow me to quickly navigate to the function and have autocomplete capabilities.  In autocomplete.php, I can have `@property Account_model $Account_model`, and then whenever I use `$this->Account_model->xxx`, autocomplete works.

When using `get_instance()`, all of this functionality dies.  For example, when in a helper class, I have to use `$CI = & get_instance();`, and then `$CI->Account_model->xxxx`.  How do you get autocomplete to work when referencing the library this way?

[Note: this is just a simple example.  My true usage is with PHPUnit, but solving the above example will allow PHPUnit to work as well.]

Comment: `/** @var MyClassName $CI */` before the `$CI` instantiation?

Comment: That will partially work, but if $CI is used to access more than one class (which it often is), then this doesn't work.  To get one particular class to work, this can work, although not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To re-bind `get_instance()` to your IDE’s autocomplete, you'll need inform it that’s an instance of the native controller for CodeIgniter. Which is`CI_Controller`:

```
/**
 * Example MyClass Library within
 * /application/libraries/
**/
class MyClass {

    /**
     * @var CI_Controller
    **/
    private $ci;

    /**
     * Init MyClass 
    **/ 
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!  `@var CI_Controller` seems so simple, but without that exact syntax, it had been a no-go.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

can you try writing properties before starting class like this

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * @property  usermodel $usermodel
 * @property  groupmodel $groupmodel
 * @property  tablemodel $tablemodel
 * @property  ion_auth $ion_auth
 * @property  db_table_model $db_table_model
 * @property  apimodel $apimodel
 * @property  chartmodel $chartmodel
 * @property  todomodel $todomodel
 * @property  messagemodel $messagemodel
 * @property  photomodel $photomodel
 * @property  settingsmodel $settingsmodel
 * @property  backupmodel $backupmodel
 */
class Ajax extends MX_Controller
{
  public $data;

  public function __construct()
  {
```

Comment: This is how I have it written within autocomplete.php.  The problem is that doesn't work when using `get_instance()` because the class is no longer accessed by just `$usermodel`.  It is accessed by something like `$CI->usermodel->xx`.